# java.io.IOException: There are no more files - (when copying a pdf to another location)

Tags: java, java-io, ioexception

I inherited this code that contains a function that copies a .pdf file from one location to another, creating new folders (named by hash value) in the process, and saves the new path to a database that a BI tool later uses to access the file via an API.

After we moved the file server to a new host, and quadruple checked the permissions and path references, we receive this java.io.ioexception when copying the files to the new location in the code. The copy fails, the folders aren't created where applicable, and the files are not accessible through the API.

The log files show that the program correctly identifies the source file, and correctly builds the destination path.

Any ideas as to what is causing this IOexception? Haven't encountered this one before, and I can't seem to find a relatable thread anywhere on the internet.

Function:

```
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

public boolean pushFile(File file, String newFileName)
{
    File newFile = new File(SAN_LOCATION + "\\" + newFileName.subSequence(0, 2) + "\\" + newFileName);

    try
    {

        System.out.print("Copying " + file.getName() + " to: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath());
        FileUtils.copyFile(file, newFile);
        System.out.println(" - Good file transfer");

    } catch (IOException ex)
    {
        System.out.println(" - Bad file transfer");
        Logger.getLogger(Utilities.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Log Snippet:

```
Copying ARC FERM 2019-06-18 07-35-58_AM0000006.pdf to: \\tf-fs-1\arcstor\fc\fc3533e07547850176b671730ddccfcc - Bad file transfer
java : Jun 18, 2019 11:01:27 AM datatosql.PushToSQL pushFile
At C:\arc\ch_agilent_hplc.ps1:2 char:1
+ java -jar ".\Agilent.jar" CH HPLC "$file" 2>&1 | Out-File C:\arc\Logs\Agilent\ch ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Jun 18, 2019 11...hToSQL pushFile:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: There are no more files
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1076)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1040)
    at datatosql.PushToSQL.pushFile(PushToSQL.java:763)
    at datatosql.PushToSQL.push(PushToSQL.java:508)
    at agilent.Agilent.main(Agilent.java:503)
    enter code here
```

Comment: Hmm, the slashes are properly escaped. Besides, the unc path hasn’t actually changed and was functional before the file server work. Can anyone help me define this ioexception?

Answer (score 2):

Googling "There are no more files" finds people who are having issues with security software, particularly ASUS Data Security Manager. So I suspect that the problem is not in your Java code. You can prove this by manually copying a file, something like this:

```
copy some.file "\\tf-fs-1\arcstor\fc\fc3533e07547850176b671730ddccfcc"
```

I got the path from your error message, but check it's correct! I think that you need the quotes around the path. My guess is that this won't work because it's being blocked by something on the remote machine.

Comment: That was a great idea, and a pretty obvious test I'm a bit shamed to say I hadn't tried. However, I just ran the test with the source file and was able to copy it into the target folder. Doesn't look like that's it unfortunately. Investigation continues.

Comment: As a side note, I don't believe it's the code since I'm using the same compiled jar from before the file server work was done, and it was functioning well enough before. Permissions was my first idea, but I've looked at what I could and couldn't see it. My next train of thought was that it was a space issue, but the file server has plenty of free space.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem.  In my case, I was using `FileUtils.copyFile(file, newFile)` in a loop.  After 258 successful copies, I would get that error.  I altered my code to use [`Files.copy(sourcePath, destPath)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) instead, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with our java-compiled ETL jobs designed with Talend Open Studio. A job would copy 1..n files before suddenly just failing one with fatal error. I did not identify a root cause but I implemented a try-catch which re-tries to save the file in case of a such a problem and a re-try always was succesfull in saving the file. So no idea why this happens, but it's seemingly random and does not seem to depend on the file itself or even the target directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).